# Array field in elasticsearch returning only matching elements

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I have an index in elasticsearch (tire) with an array field and custom analyzer for ngram with min_ngram = 1 and max_ngram = 10.

Field example

```
field1: [foo, bar, bof]
```

I construct a query with value of the field1 'f' and it returns the documents containing 'f' in one of the value in field1.

Question: Is is possible to return only matching values in array, e.g. in case of field1 and query 'f', only 
'foo' and 'bof' will be return and 'bar' will be ommited, e.g. field1: [foo, bof]?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you managed to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that applying highlighter in the elastic search query.
where in the response you will get extra highlight field with only matched values.